# First Order Non-Homogeneous Linear Recurrence for Summation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I've been studying Linear Recurrences in the non-homogeneous case, but have gotten stuck with the following problem: Find a closed form for $s_n=\sum_{i=1}^n i$. I know the answer is $n(n+1)/2$ by other methods, but I cannot seem to get the right answer using the recursion methods.

Here's my attempt: The sequence satisfies the non-homogeneous recurrence $s_n-s_{n-1}=n$. So consider the associated homogeneous recurrence $\overline{s_n}-\overline{s_{n-1}}=0$. This obviously has solution $\overline{s_n}=C_1$ for some constant $C_1$.

Next we find try to find a particular solution. Since the non-homogeneous part is linear, we should guess $s^{(p)}_n = A n+B$ for constants $A$ and $B$. But then, substituting back into the original recurrence, gives $(An+B)-(A(n-1)+B) = A$. It is impossible for the constant $A$ to equal the variable $n$. And so I'm stuck.

I'm guessing that I should have tried a particular solution that was a quadratic, but in all the books I've looked at, the particular solution has degree equal to the non-homogeneous part.

So what I am doing wrong?

Comment: "Using the recursion method" means showing that $s_0=0(0+1)/2$ and that if $s_n=n(n+1)/2$ then $s_{n+1}=(n+1)(n+2)/2$. The approach you explain simply postpones solving the recursion to the second step when one looks for a particular solution.

Comment: @Did: I think you're confusing an induction proof with the method of solving recurrence relations. I want to arrive at $s_n=n(n+1)/2$ using methods similar to: http://www.eecs.yorku.ca/course_archive/2008-09/S/1019/Website_files/21-linear-recurrences.pdf

Comment: Sending me to notes about solutions of linear recurrence relations is sweet, I am most sensible to the attention...  More seriously, what do you call recursion *methods*?

Comment: The method I'm referring to is the method where you form your solution as a homogeneous solution plus a particular solution.

Comment: Not sure anybody call this a recursion method... Anyway, in the present case, *as I explained in my first comment*, this is a deadend because this reports all the work on finding a particular solution.

Comment: Would you prefer "using the theory of linear recurrence relations"? The point stands: How do you find the solution you gave in your initial comment? Show me the steps so I can apply it to harder cases.

Comment: Right, now that your confused terminology is out of the way, let us turn to the maths: if $s_n-s_{n-1}=p(n)$ then $s_n=s_0+q(n)$ with $q(n)=p(1)+p(2)+\cdots+p(n)$. If $p$ is a polynomial of degree $k$, then $q$ is a polynomial of degree $k+1$. To find $q$ when $p(n)=n$, one can try $s_n=1$ (but then $s_n-s_{n-1}=0$, not interesting), $s_n=n$ (then $s_n-s_{n-1}=1$) and $s_n=n^2$ (then $s_n-s_{n-1}=2n-1$) hence a linear combination of $s_n=n^2$ and $s_n=n$ will work. If $s_n-cs_{n-1}=p(n)$ and $c\ne1$ then $s_n$ polynomial of degree $k$ works. ...

Comment: ... A more theoretical setting is to note that the transform $L$ defined by $(Lp)(X)=p(X)-p(X-1)$ on $K[X]$ is linear with kernel $K_0[X]$ and $L(K_{k+1}[X])=K_{k}[X]$ for every $k$. Likewise, if $c\ne1$, $L$ defined by $(Lp)(X)=p(X)-cp(X-1)$ on $K[X]$ is linear with kernel $\{0\}$ and $L(K_{k}[X])=K_{k}[X]$ for every $k$. The results above follow.

Comment: So, just to double check I understand, when a 1st order non-homogenous linear recurrence has the associated homogeneous linear recurrence $s_n-s_{n-1}=0$, it's a special case wherein the particular solution (in fact the solution) does not look like the non-homogeneous part. But then this begs the question: what if $s_n-s_{n-1}=\sin(n)$ or some other non-polynomial. What is the general method then?

Comment: When the RHS is $n$, the particular solution does look like the RHS. When the RHS is $\sin n$, playing with $\cos n$ and $\sin n$ shows a solution is a linear combination of these, which does look like the RHS. In full generality, a solution of $s_n-s_{n-1}=p(n)$ is $s_n=q(n)$ with $q(n)=p(n)+\cdots+p(1)$, as was already mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer/explanation in "Discrete and Combinatorial Mathematics" by Grimaldi. He first gives the general rule:

> [I]f a summand $f_1(n)$ of $f(n)$ is a constant multiple of a solution of the associated homogeneous relation... we multiply the particular solution $a_{n_1}^{(p)}$ corresponding to $f_1(n)$ by the smallest power of $n$, say $n^s$, for which no summand of $n^s f_1(n)$ is a solution of the associated homogeneous relation.

He then goes on to demonstrate this in the case $a_{n+1}-a_n=n$:

> We might think that the particular solution is $A_1n+A_0$ for constants $A_0$ and $A_1$. But here the associated homogeneous relation is $a_{n+1}=a_n$. ... Therefore, the summand $A_0$ is a solution of the associated homogeneous relation. Consequently, the [rule] above tells us that we must multiply $A_1n+A_0$ by the smallest power of $n$ for which we no longer have any constant summand. This is accomplished by multiplying $A_1n+A_0$ by $n^1$, and so we find here that $$a_n^{(p)}=A_1n^2+A_0n.$$

Answer (score 0):

The thing is,
you want the difference
$s_n-s_{n-1}$
to be $n$,
a polynomial of degree *one*.

Something you should, do, 
or will know
is that the first difference
of a polynomial of
degree $m$
is a polynomial of degree $m-1$.

Therefore,
to make the difference
of a polynomial
to have degree $1$,
the polynomial has to be
of degree $2$.

Once you see this,
the rest should be
relatively routine.

Comment: Is this just a special case then? If I had $s_n-2s_{n-1}=n$ then the particular solution would just be linear.